# Should I do scale filter before any other filters?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to apply multiple video filters in ffmpeg. I may use one or all of these filters: yadif, hqd,nlmeans,curve,convolution and scale. Assuming ffmpeg reads and does filter one at the time from left to right, Which filter should be done first or last? Specially the scale filter should be very last or first?

Comment: Apply scale at end.

Comment: Thanks. Would you elaborate. wouldn't any filter correction amplified by doing upscaling at the end? I would mostly will do upscaling than downscaling.

Comment: Deinterlacing should be done with source fields. Noise will be amplified if you upscale before.

Comment: If I understanding you correctly, I should start with yadif or any other deinterlacing, then and all other filters and finally end with scaling filter.

Comment: That's right...

Comment: @Gyan Feel free to post these as answers so that the questions can be marked as accepted. Even if they're short.

Comment: I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

[According to @Gyan](https://superuser.com/questions/1343393/should-i-do-scale-filter-before-any-other-filters#comment2011244_1343393):

> deinterlacing should be done with source fields. Noise will be amplified if you upscale before

So one should start with yadif or any other deinterlacing, then all other filters, and finally end with the scaling filter.